# 401 Authorization required error on website

Tags: html

So I just wanted to see a website I created with Wordpress and I got this message :

```
Authorization Required

This server could not verify that you are authorized to access the document requested. Either you supplied the wrong credentials (e.g., bad password), or your browser doesn't understand how to supply the credentials required.
```

It used to work just fine and I haven't changed a single thing. A pop-up window asks for a username/password and the one I use to access WP configuration does not work. Any idea?? I'm pretty scared I got hacked or something.

Comment: It sounds like the resource you are requesting is behind basic HTTP authentication. Do you have access to the server?

Comment: Yes, I can access it with ftp

Comment: Check to see if there's an `.htaccess` file in the directory of the resource you are trying to hit.

Comment: Yes there is one!

Comment: Read it. Are there some credentials in it? If so, try that user/pass combination for your resource.

Comment: Okay read it but i'm not sure where to find this combination. Not sure there is one actually. There's another file that's named .htpasswd and there's a long thing that looks like a password but no username.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154489/discussion-between-jorge-valle-and-twister013).

Comment: Server configuration issues are for serverfault.com. SO is for programming questions.

Answer (score 0):

Enter the wp-admin directory. Now you will see the password settings in the control panel. Uncheck the "Password protect this directory" option and click on the Save option.

If the problem still persists...

Delete the .htaccess file

or

Disable all WordPress plugins (Rename Plugins Folder).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Delete the .htaccess file and save permalink again.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

If you havent changed anything, probably this is a problem from the host. Send them a ticket or use live chat.